# Cannot resolve symbol DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, dagger2, dagger

Есть мой проект на GitHub - https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/MVVM_FLOW
я не использовал его много времени, и сегодня я решил проверить что там, в результате я столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами компиляции/Gradle/build, в общем после того как я обновил некоторые зависимости, похоже что билд проходит, но при компиляции я получаю ошибку

> error: cannot find symbol
> import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.components.DaggerAppComponent;

Насколько я понимаю, то проблема в dependency которые я подключаю, я проверил несколько ответов на SO и вроде как все правильно, но все равно проблема осталась

Если удобно то можно проверить код в репозитории (ссылку я указал выше) или я могу запостить тут градл и класс где получаю ошибку

Есть мои зависимости Grale

```
...
    //Dependency Injection
    api "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3"
    api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1"
    api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.3" // if you use the support libraries
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.28.3"
...
```

и есть мой класс, где я получил ошибку:

```
package com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di;

import android.content.Context;

import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.components.AppComponent;
import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.components.BaseComponent;
import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.components.BaseComponentBuilder;
import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.components.DaggerAppComponent;
import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.moduls.AppModule;
import com.example.krokosha.quizyourself.di.moduls.BaseModule;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;

public class ComponentsHolder
{
    private final Context context;
    
    @Inject
    Map<Class<?>, Provider<BaseComponentBuilder>> builders;
    
    private Map<Class<?>, BaseComponent> components;
    private AppComponent appComponent;
    
    public ComponentsHolder(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public ComponentsHolder init()
    {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(context)).build();
        appComponent.injectComponentsHolder(this);
        components = new HashMap<>();
        return this;
    }
    
    public BaseComponent getBaseComponent(Class<?> cls)
    {
        return getBaseComponent(cls, null);
    }
    
    public BaseComponent getBaseComponent(Class<?> cls, BaseModule module)
    {
        BaseComponent component = components.get(cls);
        
        if (component == null)
        {
            BaseComponentBuilder builder = builders.get(cls).get();
            
            if (module != null)
            {
                builder.module(module);
            }
            
            component = builder.build();
            components.put(cls, component);
        }
        
        return component;
    }
    
    public void releaseBaseComponent(Class<?> cls)
    {
        components.put(cls, null);
    }
}
```

Что я пропустил?

**UPD**
Заменил зависимости дагера на вот такие

```
...
    //Dependency Injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.35.1"
...
```

Comment: а почему у вас всё разных версий?

Comment: @IR42 заменил зависимости и добавил в вопрос апдейт, все равно не помагает